# Using function name as string to call a callable function from another class

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is to call a function from the class called `GeneralRules` using the data I extracted. I use the `rulename` var to call the function. I tried to use `call_user_func`, but it returned a fatal error.

```
<?php
namespace Validat;
require_once '\..\vendor\autoload.php';
use Rules\GeneralRules;
class Validator
{
    private $RuleName,$GRules;
    private $_Fields=[];
    public function __construct(){
    $this->GRules = new GeneralRules;
    }
    public function ExtractData(array $Rule){
        foreach ($Rule as $key => $values){
            $this->RuleName = $key;
            $this->_Fields = $values;
        }
        if (is_callable($this->GRules->{$this->RuleName}(""))){
            echo "Callable";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1: the code that triggers the error

```
    <?php
namespace Validat;
require_once '\..\vendor\autoload.php';
use Rules\GeneralRules;
use Errors\ErrorHandler;
use Errors\Errors;
class Validator
{
    private $RuleName,$GRules,$ErrorH;
    private $_Fields=[],$_Errors=[];
    public function __construct(){
    $this->GRules = new GeneralRules;
    $this->ErrorH = new ErrorHandler;
    }
    public function ExtractData(array $Rule){
        foreach ($Rule as $key => $values){
            $this->RuleName = $key;
            $this->_Fields = $values;
        }
        var_dump($this->_Fields);
        if (is_callable(array($this->GRules,$this->RuleName)))
           if( call_user_func($this->GRules->$this->RuleName,$this->_Fields[1])){
               echo "pass";
           }
           else 
               $this->_Errors=$this->ErrorH->AddError($this->_Fields[0].' '.Errors::get('Errors/'.$this->RuleName));
    }
}
```

Comment: You acutally don't use call_user_func(). Can you add that? What error did it throw?

Comment: @hek2mgl call_user_func return call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given . i didn't include it because if statement return false i don't know why when i use $this->GRules->{$this->RuleName}("") without is_Callable it work fine.

Comment: Shouldn't your if-condition be within the foreach loop? If $Rule is an array with multiple values you are only addressing the last value, while you are overwriting the values in the foreach loop.

Comment: @RST $rule hold 3 values and i store all values in $_fields array and it contain all of them not just the last value .

Comment: Is it possible for you to show the whole code? The interconnected classes as well? Pastebin?

Comment: @ArvinSloane Please *show* the code that triggers the error

Comment: Why do you use `call_user_func()` at all? Just `$this->GRules->$this->RuleName($this->_Fields[1]);` That's it!

Comment: `( call_user_func(array($this->GRules,$this->RuleName),$this->_Fields[1]))` this works for me.

Comment: Again, why do you use `call_user_func()`. You can simply *call* the function. That's what a function is meant for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (is_callable(array($this->GRules,$this->RuleName)))
   if( call_user_func($this->GRules->$this->RuleName,$this->_Fields[1])){
```

The problem is in front of your eyes: you check if a symbol is callable but you pass something else to `call_user_func()`.

This is how you should do it:

```
if (is_callable(array($this->GRules, $this->RuleName)))
   if (call_user_func(array($this->GRules, $this->RuleName), $this->_Fields[1])){
```

#### Why the original code does not work?

It does not work as you tried because PHP interprets the expression `$this->GRules->$this->RuleName` from left to right:

- `$this->GRules` is an object of type `GeneralRules`;
- `$this->GRules->$this`: the second `$this` is converted to string (it's probably `object` if class `Validator` does not implement `__toString()`) and `$this->GRules` most probably does not have a property `object`; this makes `$this->GRules->$this` to evaluate to `NULL`;
- on the last step, `NULL` does not have the property `RuleName` and this triggers the fatal error.

You can hint PHP about how you want this expression to be evaluated by using curly braces around `$this->RuleName`:

```
if (call_user_func($this->GRules->{$this->RuleName}, $this->_Fields[1])){
```

This way PHP knows that `$this->RuleName` must be evaluated first; it produces a string out of it and then replaces it into the big expression to get what you need.

I recommend you use the first way exposed on top; it is more clear for the reader what you want to do: call method whose name is stored in `$this->RuleName` of the object stored in `$this->GRules`.